# How can we read multiple json files one after one using jquery

Tags: javascript

can we read multiple json files one after one using jQuery.get() method? or else any possible way is there to read multiple json files one after one

Comment: Loop through them.

Comment: store the JSON filename or web service URL in an array and you can loop through them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ***Jquery.when***

```
 var a=$.get(url1);
 var b=$.get(url2);
 $.when(a,b).done(function(aResult,bResult)
 {
   console.log(aResult[0]+"   "+bResult[0]);

  }
```

Here the url1 and url2 are returning JSON responses or you can replace url1 and url2 with your JSON file name on the server

Answer (score 0):

We don't need JQuery only vanilla JavaScript *(ES6/ES2019)*

**Pure functional** promise-based fetchAll()

It's looks complicated but it's really simple.

```
    const fetchAll = files => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        Promise.all(Object.values(files).map(file => fetch(file)))
               .then(responses =>
                      Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.json()))
                             .then(jsons =>
                                 resolve(Object.keys(files).reduce((prev, curr, index) =>
                                     !(prev[curr] = jsons[index]) || prev, {}))
                             ))
               .catch(err => reject(err))
    );
```

Using

```
    fetchAll({
        example1: 'http://domainxxxxxxx.com/example1.json',
        example2: 'http://domainxxxxxxx.com/example2.json',
    }).then(jsons => {
        console.log(jsons)  // <-- Result here
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err.message);
    });
```

or modern **Async/Await** way

```
    const main = async () => {
        const [example1, example2] = await fetchAll({
            example1: 'http://domainxxxxxxx.com/example1.json',
            example2: 'http://domainxxxxxxx.com/example2.json',
        });
        console.log(example1, example2);        
    } 
    main();
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work. It uses the fetch api and promises. [Here is the demo link.](http://jsbin.com/hofare/edit?html,js,output)
This downloads one by one. You can use Promise.all and simplify this code if concurrent download is ok.

```
var files = [
  'https://rawgit.com/blessenm/ng-app-kit/master/app/config/dev.json',
  'https://rawgit.com/blessenm/ng-app-kit/master/app/config/prod.json'
];

function fetchFiles(files) {
  var promise = Promise.resolve();

  files.forEach((file) => {
    promise = promise
                .then(() => fetch(file))
                .then(response => response.json());
  });

  return promise;
}

function startFetching() {
  fetchFiles(files).then(function(result) {
    //Here fetching is complete

    alert(JSON.stringify(result)); // Final json file
    alert('Complete');
  });
}
```